# html crops height video to height 100vh, video to fullscreen

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I am struggling with a stupid little thing. Working on this [site](http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/p2_vc/):

(sorry for the slow server, school stuff you know)

The video you'll see is on height vh100, which is what i want. When I have this video on the max height of your browser the width of the video is not fullscreen.
The code I have now:

**HTML**

```html
<!-- video -->
<video id="moodvideo" autoplay loop>
    <source src="moodvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

**CSS**

```css
/* Video */
video {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is the video on full screen, `width 100wh` and `height 100vh`. If the `height` (of the video with width 100wh) is bigger then the `height 100vh`, I want the video to crop so it will be on fullscreen view on the `max width` and `height` your browser. By cropping, I don't bother to missing some of the video (50px from the bottom or so), fullscreen in `width` and `height` is more important to me.

Now, I already searched and tried a lot before asking you guys, things like; `vw100/vh100`, `min-height/width 100`, add the movie in a `div`, `div` to `100 vh/vw`, and some scripts I found but nothing really works...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the jquery videoBG plugin: http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/

Or you could add the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/wcv2ak9p/1/

The alternative image is displayed when the browser doesn't support the video.

**HTML**

```
<video id="moodvideo" autoplay loop>
    <source src="moodvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <img id="alternative" src="alternative.jpg" />
</video>
```

**CSS**

```
#moodvideo, #alternative {
    width: 100vw; /* Could also use width: 100%; */
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: fixed; /* Change position to absolute if you don't want it to take up the whole page */
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, for real! the last does the job(and is the most simple way for me)!!!!! trying for hours so thanks!!!!:D

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)

Comment: Note: `object-fit` isn't currently supported by [IE](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/objectfitandobjectposition). You'll have to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit)

Comment: I am not that fan of IE, so who's visiting my site with IE has to download something els ^^. Its for school, still first year so that isn't that big deal. Although thanks for mention it!